# Problem when trying to copy a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, copy

So I am starting to use C, and I have some problems almost always with memory allocation. Basically I am getting stuck when I am trying to copy a struct to another struct.

I will put you the code here:
The headers file is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

//declaration constants
#define MAX_NAME 15+1
#define SEATS_PERCENTAGE 0.95
#define IN_TIME 60
#define OUT_TIME 120

//type declarations
typedef enum {FORBIDDEN, ALLOWED_WITH_COMPANION, ALLOWED} tFairgroundRideAccess;

typedef struct{
    tFairgroundRideAccess lessThan100;
    tFairgroundRideAccess between100_120;
    tFairgroundRideAccess between120_140;
    tFairgroundRideAccess greaterThan140;
} tFairgroundRideHeightRequirement;

typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    tFairgroundRideHeightRequirement accessHeight;
    int durationTrip;
    int numPersonsTrip;
    int peopleInQueue;
} tFairgroundRide;

tFairgroundRide myFairgroundRide;

//define function headers
void readFairgroundRide(tFairgroundRide *fRide);
void writeFairgroundRide(tFairgroundRide fRide);
void copyFairgroundRide(tFairgroundRide fRideSrc, tFairgroundRide *fRideDst);
int waitingTime (tFairgroundRide fRide, int people);
bool accessWithoutCompanion (tFairgroundRide fRide, int height);
void selectFairgroundRide (tFairgroundRide fRide1, tFairgroundRide fRide2, int people1, int people2, int height2);
```

The file with the functions is the following one (what I want to check **why I am not allocating properly in memory the new copy in the function copyFairgroundRide**):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "fairgroundRide.h"

void readFairgroundRide(tFairgroundRide *fRide){
    printf("NAME >> \n");
    scanf("%s", fRide->name);
    getchar();
    printf("ACCESS HEIGHT, LESSTHAN100 (0-FORBIDDEN, 1-ALLOWED_WITH_COMPANION, 2-ALLOWED) >> \n");
    scanf("%d", &fRide->accessHeight.lessThan100);
    getchar();
    printf("ACCESS HEIGHT, BETWEEN100_120 (0-FORBIDDEN, 1-ALLOWED_WITH_COMPANION, 2-ALLOWED) >> \n");
    scanf("%d", &fRide->accessHeight.between100_120);
    getchar();
    printf("ACCESS HEIGHT, BETWEEN120_140 (0-FORBIDDEN, 1-ALLOWED_WITH_COMPANION, 2-ALLOWED) >> \n");
    scanf("%d", &fRide->accessHeight.between120_140);
    getchar();
    printf("ACCESS HEIGHT, GREATERTHAN140 (0-FORBIDDEN, 1-ALLOWED_WITH_COMPANION, 2-ALLOWED) >> \n");
    scanf("%d", &fRide->accessHeight.greaterThan140);
    getchar();
    printf("TRIP DURATION >> \n");
    scanf("%d", &fRide->durationTrip);
    getchar();
    printf("NUMBER OF PERSONS ON A TRIP >> \n");
    scanf("%d", &fRide->numPersonsTrip);
    getchar();
}

void writeFairgroundRide(tFairgroundRide fRide){
    printf("NAME: %s\n", fRide.name);
    printf("ACCESS HEIGHT, LESSTHAN100 (0-FORBIDDEN, 1-ALLOWED_WITH_COMPANION, 2-ALLOWED): %d\n",fRide.accessHeight.lessThan100);
    printf("ACCESS HEIGHT, LESSTHAN100 (0-FORBIDDEN, 1-ALLOWED_WITH_COMPANION, 2-ALLOWED): %d\n",fRide.accessHeight.between100_120);
    printf("ACCESS HEIGHT, LESSTHAN100 (0-FORBIDDEN, 1-ALLOWED_WITH_COMPANION, 2-ALLOWED): %d\n",fRide.accessHeight.between120_140);
    printf("ACCESS HEIGHT, LESSTHAN100 (0-FORBIDDEN, 1-ALLOWED_WITH_COMPANION, 2-ALLOWED): %d\n",fRide.accessHeight.greaterThan140);
    printf("TRIP DURATION: %d\n", fRide.durationTrip);
    printf("NUMBER OF PERSONS ON A TRIP: %d\n", fRide.numPersonsTrip);
}

void copyFairgroundRide(tFairgroundRide fRideSrc, tFairgroundRide *fRideDst){
    strcpy(fRideDst->name,fRideSrc.name);
    fRideDst->accessHeight.lessThan100 = fRideSrc.accessHeight.lessThan100;
    fRideDst->accessHeight.between100_120 = fRideSrc.accessHeight.between100_120;
    fRideDst->accessHeight.between120_140 = fRideSrc.accessHeight.between120_140;
    fRideDst->accessHeight.greaterThan140 = fRideSrc.accessHeight.greaterThan140;
    fRideDst->durationTrip = fRideSrc.durationTrip;
    fRideDst->numPersonsTrip = fRideSrc.numPersonsTrip;
    fRideDst->peopleInQueue = fRideSrc.peopleInQueue;
}

int waitingTime (tFairgroundRide fRide, int people){
    int result;
    result = ((IN_TIME+OUT_TIME+(fRide.durationTrip*60)) * (fRide.numPersonsTrip * SEATS_PERCENTAGE) * people);
    return result;
}

bool accessWithoutCompanion (tFairgroundRide fRide, int height){
    if (height < 100 && fRide.accessHeight.lessThan100 == 2){
        return true;
    }
    if(height >= 100 && height<120 && fRide.accessHeight.between100_120 == 2){
        return true;
    }
    if(height >= 120 && height<=140 && fRide.accessHeight.between120_140 == 2){
        return true;
    }
    if (height > 140 && fRide.accessHeight.greaterThan140 == 2){
        return true;
    }else{
            return false;
    }
}


void selectFairgroundRide (tFairgroundRide fRide1, tFairgroundRide fRide2, int people1, int people2, int height2){
    if((accessWithoutCompanion(fRide1,height2) == true) && (waitingTime(fRide1,people1)<=waitingTime(fRide2,people2))){
        copyFairgroundRide(fRide1,&myFairgroundRide);
    }
    if((accessWithoutCompanion(fRide1,height2) == true) && (accessWithoutCompanion(fRide2,height2)==false)){
        copyFairgroundRide(fRide1,&myFairgroundRide);
    }
    if((accessWithoutCompanion(fRide1,height2) == false) && (accessWithoutCompanion(fRide2,height2))){
        copyFairgroundRide(fRide2,&myFairgroundRide);
    }
}
```

And the main code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "fairgroundRide.h"

int main(){

    tFairgroundRide myFairgroundRide;
    tFairgroundRide fairgroundRide1;
    tFairgroundRide fairgroundRide2;
    int height1,people1,people2;

    printf("ENTER DATA FOR FIRST FAIRGROUND RIDE >>\n");
    readFairgroundRide(&fairgroundRide1);
    printf("ENTER THE PEOPLE IN THE QUEUE OF FAIRGROUND RIDE 1 >> \n");
    scanf("%d", &people1);
    getchar();
    printf("ENTER DATA FOR SECOND FAIRGROUND RIDE >>\n");
    readFairgroundRide(&fairgroundRide2);
    printf("ENTER THE PEOPLE IN THE QUEUE OF FAIRGROUND RIDE 2 >> \n");
    scanf("%d", &people2);
    getchar();
    printf("ENTER THE HEIGHT >> \n");
    scanf("%d", &height1);
    getchar();
    selectFairgroundRide(fairgroundRide1,fairgroundRide2,people1,people2,height1);
    printf("RESULTS:\n");
    writeFairgroundRide(myFairgroundRide);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

So when I am running the program I can get all the info of both inputs, faigroundRide1 and fairgroundRide2, but if I copy it to another struct called myFairgroundRide I start getting weird characters and numbers, and I know that is due to memory allocation but I cannot find why or where is the issue. If you need further explanations about the code or what is my doubt just let me know and I will try to re-do it in another way.

Thanks in advance,
Jorge.

Comment: `writeFairgroundRide(myFairgroundRide);` but `myFairgroundRide` is not initialized.

Comment: Seems you forgot to call `copyFairgroundRide()`

Comment: Also, in `selectFairgroundRide`, `myFairgroundRide` _is not visible!_ Hence you _can't_ copy to this variable. (As HAL9000 found, there are two declartions of the variable.)

Comment: I call the function copyFairgroundRide within the function selectFairgroundRide() Where I set some conditions and depending if those conditions matches or not I copy either fairgroundRide1 or fairgroundRide2 to myFairgroundRide. Where should I declare or call this function if is not well declared?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, `selectFairgroundRide`, does not modify its parameters, so pointers are not strictly necessary.  Although it is a good practice when structures are large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `myFairgroundRide`. One in global scope, and one as local variable in `main`. In `selectFairgroundRide` you copy to the global one, but later in `main` you print the local one.

And by the way, `copyFairgroundRide` can be simplified:

```
void copyFairgroundRide(tFairgroundRide fRideSrc, tFairgroundRide *fRideDst)
{
   *fRideDst = fRideSrc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So basically I need to transform my local variable to a global one right ? The way to do so would be not declaring it in main ?

Thank you!

Comment: What you probably want to do, is to pass `fairgroundRide1` and `fairgroundRide1` as pointers to `selectFairgroundRide`, and just return one of those pointers.

Comment: Okay thanks for the fast replies!
So right now if I remove the global variable and I only leave the one in the main method. When I use myFairgroundRide in selectFairgroundRide will tell me that myFairgroundRide is undeclared even if is declared at the beginning of the main method.

EDIT: I need to use the copymethod, that's why I am copying from fairgrondRide1 or 2 to selectFairgroundRide, how could I do that returning one of those pointers to the variable myFairgroundRide ?

Comment: `selectFairgroundRide` doesn't know about any local variables in `main`, so you have to pass a pointer to `myFairgroundRide`  as a parameter if `selectFairgroundRide` should modify it. You can also return  `fRide1` or `fRide2` as a return value, and assign it to `myFairgroundRide` in main. But as I said in my previous comment, it is probably better to work with pointers.

Comment: You are the GOAT! Thanks a lot! @HAL9000